# $.getJSON Working in Chrome and IE8+, but not Firefox32.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firefox

I have researched for a solution for the past few hours and am stumped. I have a simple button calling a function requesting JSON data:

```
function testJson(){
  $.getJSON( '../shared/languages/test.json', function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and IE8+, but not Firefox32.0.1. Here is what the JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "one": "Singular sensation",
    "two": "Beady little eyes",
    "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

I have used Firebug to ensure the file is returning a response and it does return the JSON data, but the console will not write it out and any js that comes within does not run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Yes, I have used the developer tools and there are no JS errors, and the Net tab does show a response with the data I am retrieving.

Comment: try adding a `.error()` handler to see if it goes in there

Comment: I modified it to $.getJSON( '../shared/languages/test.json', function( data ) {
alert('success');
}).success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); }); and the error and complete alerts run, but neither of the successes fire.

Comment: do a `console.log(arguments)` in the error function and inspect the object in the console to see what is going on

Comment: It looks like there is a parse error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". The response text is a bunch of strange characters.

Comment: After wrestling with some working examples, it turns our Coda encoded my JSON files with something other than UTF-8, which was causing the error. Once I used a text editor to save my json file as utf-8, it ran without issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wrestling with some working examples, it turns our Coda encoded my JSON files with something other than UTF-8, which was causing the error. Once I used a text editor to save my json file as utf-8, it ran without issue. Thanks for the help!